# Emulate a number of columns for a program in the terminal

Tags: terminal, columns, terminal-emulator, taskwarrior

I have a program that I'd like to run, deluding it to believe that my terminal has less columns than it does, because that enables its native truncation, which I need.

I tried `resize` from `xterm` as suggested [on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852105/is-there-a-terminal-command-that-changes-the-terminal-window-dimensions), however, that only works properly within xterm and can hardly be scripted.
I need something that I can use within a script to get the output of a [taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/) command.

Exporting a different value for `COLUMNS` doesn't seem to change anything unfortunately.

Comment: downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

The community answer is on the right track.

You can use `tmux` to create a detached session with the geometry that you want (column width, assume some number of rows).

```
tmux new-session -d -s task-session -x WIDTH -y HEIGHT
```

Then run your command.

```
tmux send-keys 'task' ENTER
```

Do not pipe command output to a file.

Dump the `tmux` pane to file:

```
tmux capture-pane -b temp-buffer -S -
tmux save-buffer -b temp-buffer output.txt
tmux delete-buffer -b temp-buffer
```

[Reference](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2019/10/28/how-to-store-the-contents-of-tmux-pane/)

Comment: hm yeah that is what I feared ^^ could you elaborate please?

Comment: The `tmux` man page is fairly well-written, but there's a lot there. I've updated my answer with actual commands.

Comment: Thank you, I tried many dead ends before I found this solution! I ran into a little trouble with buffers, and I got a `buffer invalid` error trying this code. But I found that `capture-pane` has a `-p` flag to print the buffer to stdout. The command that worked for me: `tmux capture-pane -t ${tmux_session}.0 -pe -S -500`.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard is, indeed, that the value of the `COLUMNS` environment variable supersedes other ways of obtaining the terminal size.
The standard describes one of the variable's purposes as "display[ing] data in an area arbitrarily smaller than the terminal or window" amongst other things, which matches what you want.

Those other ways are not standardized, but they are commonly an `ioctl()` of `TIOCGWINSZ` against a terminal device open file descriptor.
Your program does this; albeit that it just assumes without `isatty()` checks that its standard output is a terminal device.

Unfortunately, there are programs that do not respect the `COLUMNS` environment variable and yours is sadly one of them.
Instead it provides is own idiosyncratic non-standard mechanism, the `detection` and `defaultwidth` settings in its configuration file.

Adding to the sadness is that these operate the other way around to the `COLUMNS` environment variable.
They are a fallback, not an override.
You have to turn `detection` off, so that the program stops using `TIOCGWINSZ` and falls back to the default.
You have to then set a value for `defaultwidth`, which is 80 if unset and 65536 with detection forced off if zero.

Further addition to the sadness is that turning `detection` off applies to both width and height, unlike the POSIX standard `COLUMNS` and `LINES` variables which operate independently of each other.
So you have to concern yourself with a `defaultheight` as well, which is 24 if unset and 65536 with detection forced off if zero.

You *could*, alternatively, leave detection on and fool your program with a pseudo-terminal instead.
`tmux` is a complex way to achieve this, with all that key stuffing and intermediary file use.
Using Bernstein `ptybandage` and `stty columns` (against the internal pseudo-terminal) is simpler, takes one line, and outputs to standard output in real time as your program is running:

```
ptybandage sh -c 'stty columns 40 ; exec task'
```

## Further reading

- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptybandage`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptybandage.xml). *djbwares*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`ptybandage`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ptybandage.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Comment: As indicated in the linked documentation, `ptybandage` is superceded by `execlineb` which is part of the `execline` package in the AUR

Answer (score 1):

The following does not yet work, but I suspect that you could make it work with some modifications. The commands create a new tmux session and modify the size of the pane before executing taskwarrior:

```
tmux new -d -s s1
tmux split -v
tmux resize-pane -t s1 -y 5
tmux send-keys "task > output.txt" ENTER
sleep 1
tmux kill-session -t s1
cat output.txt
```