# Display the full command in smem

Tags: linux, bash

When I run `smem`, I see a truncated version of the command. Is there any way to get `smem` to display the full command? For example, this is what I see below:

```
 PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
2616 user12345 dbus-broker --log 4 --contr        0      336      414     2752 
2634 user12345 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-        0      476      501     5704 
2615 user12345 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch        0      400      521     3904
```

I'm running smem via Python and capturing the output. It would be nice to have the full command from the get-go and not have open every single `/proc` file just to check a command.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on how you are running it. It it's inside a graphical terminal and you can make it bigger, then:

```
smem -a
```

will fit as much data as it can.

You could also see [Emulate a number of columns for a program in the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616004/emulate-a-number-of-columns-for-a-program-in-the-terminal) if you'd rather fool the program into thinking it has a terminal with an arbitrary number of columns.